# How to tally and store votes for a web site?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2005.

I have a site that people can vote on awesome motorcycles.  Each time a user votes, there is one for the first bike and one vote against the second bike.  Two votes are stored in the database. The vote table looks like this:

```
VoteID VoteDate     BikeID Vote
1      2012-01-12   123    1
2      2012-01-12   125    0
3      2012-01-12   126    0
4      2012-01-12   129    1
```

I want to tally the votes for each bike quite frequently, say each hour.  My idea is to store the tally as a percentage of contest won versus lost on the bike table as an attribute of the bike. So, if a bike won 10 contests and lost 20 contest, they would have a score (tally) of 33.  I would tally up daily, weekly, and monthly scores.

```
BikeID  BikeName  DailyTally WeeklyTally MonthlyTally
1       Big Dog   5          10          50
2       Big Cat   3          15          40
3       Small Dog 9          8           0
4       Fish Face 19         21          0
```

Right now, there are about 500 votes per day being cast. We anticipate 2500 - 5000 per day in the next month or so.

What is the best way to tally the data and what is the best way to store it? Should the tallies be on their own table? Should a trigger be used to run a new tally each time a bike is voted on? Should a stored procedure be run hourly to get all tallies?

Any ideas would be very helpful!

Comment: What identifies a single contest? A `VoteDate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store your `VoteDate` as a `datetime` value instead of just `date`.

For your tallies, you can just make that a view and calculate it on the fly.  This should be very simple to do using `GROUP BY` and `DATEPART` functions.  If you need exact code for how to do this, please open a new question.

For that low volume of rows it doesn't make any sense to store aggregations in a table when you can just calculate them whenever you want to see them and get accurate and immediate results that are up-to-date.

Comment: The VoteDate is most definitely a datetime. (Thanks!) So, how many rows would there have to be before it might be a good idea to start aggregating?

Comment: As long as you have appropriate indexes you can aggregate on the fly (i.e. in your view) pretty much indefinitely.  I do this with hundreds of millions of rows without issue.

Comment: Wow! I have already taken your advice.  Over the weekend, I did set up several views to access the info I needed, last seven days, last thirty days, last ninety days, and all time. I can access these very quickly.  Thanks for your solid advice.

Comment: @EvikJames - happy to help!  This will make your life much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @JNK try a view or just a normal stored proc to calculate the outputs on the fly.  If you find it becomes too slow as your data grows I would investigate other routes then (like caching the data in another table etc).  Probably worth keeping it simple to start with; you can always resuse the logic from the SP/VIEW later if you do want to setup a scheduled task.

Edit : 
Removed the index view as per @Damien_The_Unbeliever comments its not deterministic and i'm stupid :)

Comment: Indexed view won't work if the view definition (as here seems likely) uses the *current* date.

Comment: Sorry yes you are right it has to be a deterministic function doesn't it. Ill edit and remove.  I would personally just use an SP.

Comment: VoteDate is a datetime field. I don't know if that changes anything for you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The view wouldn't have to use `GETDATE()`, but the query *selecting from the view* might (and most likely should).